# The smallest number that can be written as the sum of two or more consecutive integers in exactly 1000 ways

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation, integers

What is the smallest number that can be written as the sum of two or more consecutive integers in exactly 1000 ways?

I was reading this question from [Link](https://mathblag.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/sums-of-consecutive-integers/) . I have understood the theory behind it. But not able to solve this question.

Here number of ways $=1000$. This means $(p_2+1)(p_3+1)\cdots(p_n+1) = 1000+1 = 1001 = 7\cdot 11\cdot 13$. So according to me the answer is $(3^{13}  5^{11} \cdot 7^7)$. But how to generalise the result, because sometimes $a^b > c^d$ even when $a < b$?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know the sum of the numbers from $1$ to $n$? Can you use that to get the sum from $m$ to $n$?

Comment: You should summarize the argument and be more specific about what you don't understand. I'm sure the correct answer will have factors of $2$ You are correct that it involves the count of ways to factor the number, but I don't remember the details. If you provide that it will be easier to answer

Comment: I think the smallest number will not contain factors of 2 as it will just increase the smallest possible answer as the power of 2 does not account for the number of ways according to the formula given in the link.

Comment: The link doesn't link for me.  You should quote the result. As I recall, you need to factor the number in 1001 ways with the two factors having the same parity, but you can do that if you have factors of $2$.  You just need to make sure both factors are even.

Comment: Your link is missing and you should learn to format your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Link added. Don't know why it was not present earlier.